# registration form not working

Tags: user-registration

My website name is indiafashionhunt.com and I enabled the WooCommerce plugin and the registration form, but the problem is when I am clicking the register button after inputting all the information it's going to unlimited loop and nothing happening.

Its even not showing any call inside developer option panel in network tab, but the user is registering in the backend. Also if you click again the registration button it starting working and showing user already registered.

Sorry for my bad English, please help me what is going on with my website.

Comment: If your problem is with workflow specific to WooCommerce, this would be better aimed at its support channels.

Comment: Try activating a default WordPress theme (instead of your own theme) to see if it's something related to your theme. Also try deactivating / activating them one by one your plugins to see if it's something plugin related.

Comment: Hi thanks i already tried both way i was on the default theme only but the issue is even the default registration form is not working